# Importing packages causes Unicode error in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

In my program when I type: import matplotlib as pt, I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py", line 5
    blas_mkl_info={'libraries': ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll'], 'library_dirs': ['C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib'], 'include_dirs': ['C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\\Library\\include'], 'define_macros': [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]}
                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Any ideas why this is happening and what I can do to change this?

This is the file that it is referring to:

```
# This file is generated by C:\Minonda\conda-bld\numpy-1.11_1475607650950\work\numpy-1.11.2\setup.py
# It contains system_info results at the time of building this package.
__all__ = ["get_info","show"]

blas_mkl_info={'libraries': ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll'], 'library_dirs': ['C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib'], 'include_dirs': ['C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\\Library\\include'], 'define_macros': [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]}
openblas_lapack_info={}
blas_opt_info={'libraries': ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll'], 'library_dirs': ['C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib'], 'include_dirs': ['C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\\Library\\include'], 'define_macros': [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]}
lapack_opt_info={'libraries': ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll'], 'library_dirs': ['C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib'], 'include_dirs': ['C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\\Library\\include'], 'define_macros': [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]}
lapack_mkl_info={'libraries': ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll'], 'library_dirs': ['C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib'], 'include_dirs': ['C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\\Library\\include'], 'define_macros': [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]}

def get_info(name):
    g = globals()
    return g.get(name, g.get(name + "_info", {}))

def show():
    for name,info_dict in globals().items():
        if name[0] == "_" or type(info_dict) is not type({}): continue
        print(name + ":")
        if not info_dict:
            print("  NOT AVAILABLE")
        for k,v in info_dict.items():
            v = str(v)
            if k == "sources" and len(v) > 200:
                v = v[:60] + " ...\n... " + v[-60:]
            print("    %s = %s" % (k,v))
```

Comment: Are you sure this is caused by import matplotlib? Can you please post complete error log?

Comment: Yes any package I import, I get this error message. This is using anaconda. I created a new environment to install python 2.4 and it only happened after this. But it still happens when I use default environment python 3.5

Answer (score 1):

You're missing (several) escape-backslashes in your path strings:

```
'C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib'
```

Here python will attempt to interprete `\U` as the start of a unicode escape sequence (see e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

As you already did in parts of this string, you should replace `\` with a `\\`:

```
'C:\\Users\\hh\\Anaconda3\\Library\\lib'
```

or use raw strings:

```
r'C:\Users\hh\Anaconda3\Library\lib'
```

**EDIT:**
I only now realized, that's a file created by numpy/anaconda not by yourself. So that might be worth a ticket for them I guess...